# How to search for documents in mongodb using GoLang mongodb driver where the value in document is a string and the filter has a slice of string?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I'm not able to frame my whole question in title so here it is:

I have a slice of strings `var temp = []string{"abc","efg","xyz"}`

Now I want to search documents in collection for every element in the above slice.

I know I can do something like this:

```
for _, str:=range temp{
   collection.Find(context.background(), bson.M{"key":str})
}
```

but as you can see I will have to fire many queries.

So is there a solution where I can fire a single query to find all those documents
e.g:

```
err = collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{"key":  MY_SLICE_OF_STRING})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
// I'm not sure what is your struct, so I use bson.Raw for this example
// but you can parse into your struct in the loop.
    resultQuery := make([]bson.Raw, 0)
// you can use bson.M if you like, 
// filter := bson.M{"key": bson.M{"$in": MY_SLICE_OF_STRING}}
    filter := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "key",
            Value: bson.E{
                Key:   "$in",
                Value: MY_SLICE_OF_STRING,
            },
        },
    }
    ctx := context.background()
    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, filter)
    if err != nil {
        //Handle your error.
    }
    if err == nil {
        // you should put defer function to close your cursor,
        defer func() {
            cursor.Close(ctx)
        }()
        for cursor.Next(ctx) {
            resultQuery = append(resultQuery, cursor.Current)
        }
    }
```